# API SpreadSheets Google

Tags: google-sheets-api

when executing the code of the documentation
https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/nodejs?fbclid=IwAR0KmCnMNwsPkzuB93pB8YKaWot7IkAtxWqgLANR1Z08kuRKSl-r3DbqMrY#step_3_set_up_the_sample
, after putting the key of the URL (google account to authenticate)

**this error comes out:**

```
node: 5868) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: C
llback must be a function
in maybeCallback (fs.js: 129: 9)
in Object.writeFile (fs.js: 1156: 14)
in storeToken (C: \ Users \ ELIOT \ Desktop \ demoDialoglow \ api.js: 100: 6)
in C: \ Users \ ELIOT \ Desktop \ demoDialoglow \ api.js: 79: 7
in getTokenAsync.then.r (C: \ Users \ ELIOT \ Desktop \ demoDialoglow \ node_modules \ go
gle-auth-library \ build \ src \ auth \ oauth2client.js: 97: 51)
in process._tickCallback (internal / process / next_tick.js: 68: 7)
node: 5868) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Rejection of uncontrolled promise. This e
Ror originated either by throwing inside an asynchronous function without a capture bl
ck, or rejecting a promise that was not handled with .catch (). (Rejection ID
one)
node: 5868) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: unmanaged promise rejects are obsolete
In the future, rejections of promise that are not handled will end the N
Process .js with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Is that all of your code? Do you know which line is triggering the error?

Comment: You may or may not have to report the issue on Github

Comment: All the code is in the link

Comment: I looked, but I didn't find any `setToken` function anywhere in there

Comment: Excuse me, I meant `storeToken`

Comment: I found it at this link: https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/nodejs?hl=es-419

Comment: Here's what I can tell you. I don't know how long you've been using JS, but this error simply means that you are trying to call a function, but one of its parameters must be a function and is not. This could be the result of a typo or other simple mistake. Could you say specifically what makes you think it is in that snippet?

Comment: update this post :)

Comment: Thanks, I think I figured it out and posted an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to an update to the NodeJS fs module. Simply add an empty function as a third parameter:

`fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), function(){});`

or with ES6 syntax:

`fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), () => {});`

Refer to this post for more detail: [Why node 10 has made it mandatory to pass callback on fs.writeFile()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52392192/why-node-10-has-made-it-mandatory-to-pass-callback-on-fs-writefile)